# Update SQL Query in R DataFrame

Tags: sql, r

So im trying to convert an SQL update query in my R and I'm not really sure how to. I checked online and there are multiple ways to do it. So here is my query below:

```
UPDATE TableName 
set column1 = 38000', column2 = '6', column3 = '1' 
where column1 <= '0'
```

Anyone know how I can do this on all the rows in that dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try filtering with assignments:

```r
df[df$column1 <= 0, "column2"] = 6
df[df$column1 <= 0, "column3"] = 1
df[df$column1 <= 0, "column1"] = 38000
```

Note that we update `column1` last, as its values are used to determine the updates of the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

If your frame really has numbers for strings, inequality still sort of works, but realize that it's doing a lexicographic comparison: while `20 > 3`, unfortunately `"20" < "3"`. If your data really is numbers, then discard all of the `"` d-quotes below. (If you aren't sure and accidentally use `"`, then the data becomes strings. It's possible to undo this, but it's still something to keep in mind.)

Assuming a frame named `dat`:

### base R

A bit brute force:

```r
ind <- dat$column1 <= "0"
dat$column1[ind] <- "38000"
dat$column2[ind] <- "6"
dat$column3[ind] <- "1"
```

(The use of `ind` means we don't have to worry about the order of column updates.)

Alternatively #1,

```r
rbind(
  dat[!ind,,drop = FALSE],
  transform(
    dat[ind,,drop=FALSE],
    column1 = "38000",
    column2 = "6",
    column3 = "1"
  )
)
```

(Though the row order is disrupted there.)

Alternative #2:

```r
transform(
  dat,
  column1 = ifelse(ind, "38000", column6),
  column2 = ifelse(ind, "6", column2),
  column3 = ifelse(ind, "1", column3)
)
```

Alternative #3:

```r
dat$column1 <- ifelse(ind, "38000", x$column1)
dat$column2 <- ifelse(ind, "6", x$column2)
dat$column3 <- ifelse(ind, "1", x$column3)
```

### dplyr

(We can use the same `ind` as created above.)

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(
    column1 = if_else(ind, "38000", column1),
    column2 = if_else(ind, "6", column2),
    column3 = if_else(ind, "1", column3)
  )
```

### data.table

(No need for `ind`, it's a bit more compact here.)

```r
library(data.table)
datDT <- as.data.table(dat)
datDT[ column1 <= "0", c("column1", "column2", "column3") := .("38000", "6", "1") ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we could this with `Map`.  Create a logical index from the 'column1' ('i1'), Loop over the columns of interest ('nm1') along with the corresponding replacement values as a `vector` in `Map` and `replace` those column with those values based on 'i1' and assign the `list` of vectors back to the columns

```
i1 <- df$column1 <= 0
nm1 <- paste0("column", 1:3)
df[nm1] <- Map(function(x, y), replace(x, i1, y),
                      df[nm1], c(38000, 6, 1))
```

---

Or another approach is to make the lengths same by replicating

```
df[i1, nm1] <- c(38000, 6, 1)[col(df[nm1])][i1[col(df[nm1])]]
```

---

Or with `dplyr` with `across`.  Create keydat column with the values to replace (it can be a named vector or named list as well).  After creating a temporary logical column, loop `across` the columns of interest, replace the values in those columns by the corresponding value from keydat using `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
keydat <- tibble(column1 = 38000, column2 = 6, column3 = 1)
df %>%
  mutate(i1 = column1 <= 0,
         across(starts_with('column'), ~ 
               case_when(i1 ~ keydat[[cur_column()]], TRUE ~ .)), i1 = NULL)
```

---

Or can use `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
df[nm1] <- map2(df[nm1], c(38000, 6, 1), ~ replace(.x, i1, .y))
```

---

NOTE: All of the above methods assume the columns are `numeric`.  If they are `character` class, an option is to first convert to `numeric` class for those columns that should be numeric

```
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
```